# Laravel: Run cron job tasks simultaneously

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5

I have several tasks that I've scheduled to run at various times. Here are those tasks:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\PostGetter::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('post_getter 0 5')
            ->cron('*/15 * * * *');

        $schedule->command('post_getter 5 10')
            ->cron('*/15 * * * *');

        $schedule->command('post_getter 10 20')
            ->everyThirtyMinutes();

        $schedule->command('post_getter 20 30')
            ->hourly();
    }
}
```

In order to log when each of these tasks is run, I've added the following piece of code in the `PostGetter` class to log when the task has begun running:

```
Log::info('Post getter for {arg1} and {arg2} has started.');
```

Where `arg1` and `arg2` are the two arguments in the scheduler (e.g. `0 5` or `5 10`).

I've noticed in my log file that these scripts don't seem to run at the same time. For example, when the first task is run (`post_getter 0 5`), the second task (`post_getter 5 10`) only seems to run after the first task is done, and so on.

How can I make it so that all of the tasks listed in the `Kernel` class are run at the same time and don't have to wait for the previous task to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs / scheduled processes in Laravel are run [sequentially](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L54-L64).

There is an [article](https://alfrednutile.info/posts/106) about parallel processing of scheduled tasks in Laravel 4.3. Currently there is no parallel processing in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding custom cron jobs instead of running it through the Laravel  scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel version 5.7, If you would like to run commands in the background so that they may all run simultaneously, you may use the `runInBackground` method:

```
$schedule->command('analytics:report')
         ->daily()
         ->runInBackground();
```